# Make <li> fit the width of the <ul> using CSS

Tags: css, list

I'm trying to make the `<li>` fit the width of the `<ul>` but even with `width:auto` it doesn't work at all, and I don't know why. I tried to use `display:inline-block` but this is the same. I don't know how many tabs I will have so this is why I am not using a percentage directly.

I would like to display the list inline when I display the page on a desktop and display one `li` per line when I am on a smartphone (with media queries).

I have this:

```
<ul id='menu'>
    <li class="button"><a class='current' href='http://'>Home</a></li>
    <li class="button"><a href='http://'>Products</a></li>
    <li class="button"><a href='http://'>Support</a></li>
    <li class="button"><a href='http://'>Contact</a></li>
    <li class="button"><a href='http://'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and my CSS looks like this:

```
ul#menu
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
width:100%;
position:relative;
display:block;
height:30px;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
/*border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
border-top:1px solid #000000;*/
}

li.button {
background:transparent url(../images/nav_bg.png) repeat-x top left;
height:30px;
width:auto;
}



ul#menu li
{
display:inline-block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:auto;
}

ul#menu li a
{
display:inline-block;
color:#999999;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
padding:8px 20px 0 20px;
width:auto;
}

ul#menu li a:hover
{   
color:#FFFFFF;
height:22px;
background:transparent url(../images/nav_bg.png) 0px -30px no-repeat;       
}


ul#menu li a.current
{
display:inline-block;
height:22px;
background:transparent url(images/nav_bg.png) 0px -30px no-repeat;  
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) Why are you using `inline-block`? Why not just use `block` if you want the full width? 2) Have you tried `width:100%` instead of `width:auto`

Comment: putting **width:auto** will end up with **li** which have same width like **ul**. so it will overwrite the **inline-block** or **block**

Comment: do you looking for something like this **http://jsfiddle.net/XFCyn/1/** ??

Answer (score 87):

I've found this way to deal with single-line full-width ul where an undefined number of li elements need to be spaced out evenly:

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed; /* optional */
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Basically, it emulates a table. Works in Gecko, Webkit, IE8+.
For IE7 and downwards you should use some inline-block hackery :)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwad2jdq/)

Comment: If you need to make each cell change its size adaptive to its content, the table-layout can be set to "auto"

Answer (score 3):

Since the li count can change, I can only think of accomplishing this with javascript/jquery as you suggested.  Just divide 100 by the # of li's and set the width on each one.

```
var width = Math.floor(100 / $("ul#menu li").size());
$("ul#menu li").css('width', width + "%");
```

You will probably have to play with the width depending on padding and what not.

As a side note, If you haven't already, I recommend getting a tool like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), which will let you edit css and execute js on the fly.  It is infinitely useful for fine tuning appearances.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill the width of the `<ul>` with the five `<li>`s, you will have to give those `<li>`s a width of 20% each.
Note that you need to change some other details of the CSS if you want to make this work; e.g. with a `display:inline-block` you make the spaces between the `<li>` count, so the total width of the `<ul>` content will be more than 100% wide. I'd suggest removing the `display:inline-block` and giving them `float:left`.

Edit: Or do you want them to be distributed proportionally according to their contents? That would be a different challenge.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <style>
            body{
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            .main{
                width:650px;
                border:1px solid red;
                padding:5px;
            }
            ul {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: 0;
            }
            li{
                display: table-cell;
                width: 1%;
                float: none;
                border:1px solid green;
                margin:2px;
                padding:10px;
                text-align:center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="main">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                </ul>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}

#menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="index.html">1A1CASĂ </a></li>
  <li><a href="html-css.html">H1TML-CSS </a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript.html">J1VASCRIPT </a></li>
  <li><a href="php.html">PHP </a></li>
  <li><a href="teste.html">TESTE </a></li>
  <li><a href="constact.html">CONTACT </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Wow stumbled upon a very old question here.

For anyone also seeing this and scrolling down here, in 2022 this is easily [doable via flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
#menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id='menu'>
  <li class="button"><a class='current' href='http://'>Home</a></li>
  <li class="button"><a href='http://'>Products</a></li>
  <li class="button"><a href='http://'>Support</a></li>
  <li class="button"><a href='http://'>Contact</a></li>
  <li class="button"><a href='http://'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

try below css:

```
style.css (line 87)

ul#menu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px 0;
    width: 11.1%;
}

style.css (line 113) 

ul#menu li a.current {
    background: url("images/nav_bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -30px transparent;
    height: 22px;
    margin: 0;
}

style.css (line 95)

ul#menu li a {
    color: #999999;

    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px 20px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
}
```

see screen shot:

[image]