# Full width menu support IE7 by CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a full width menu. I have problem with IE7 since display: table-cell doesn't support in IE7. Is there any solutions beside this?

Here my code:

```
<div class="main_nav second">
     <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .main_nav ul {
        display: table;
        position: relative;
        table-layout: auto;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    }

    .main_nav ul li {
        list-style: none;
        float: none;
        display: table-cell;
    }

    .main_nav ul li a {
        padding: 10px 15px;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

I also try it with Javascript, but it works not really well when I add more items in menu.
Thank in advanced for your value time :)

Comment: is the count of menu points constant ?

Comment: I think this post may help as they were trying to do the same thing - basically if you want to do this in IE7 you will probably need to write some js to calculate the width on the fly:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894176/css-how-to-make-li-fit-the-width-of-the-ul

Answer (score 2):

Could you use `display: inline;`?

See my example here: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vqh2C/2/)

Comment: Thank you for helping to answer this problem. What I want is that the menu items need to expand its width according to the container width. Even though there are more or less, the menu still full.

Comment: Even though you are looking for a CSS only solution, I have been doing a bit of research and I'm not sure this is possible. If it is possible it is probably a "nicer" solution to use javascript/jQuery to calculate the width of the <li> tags depending on how many there are.